# C/C++ Windows 10 x64 (17763) Enterprise DACL issues

Tags: c, windows, winapi

I`m creating a user-mode process with the correct (I believe) permissions to allow the system to access an object, however this seems to always fail on some system processes with "Access Denied".

The object is created in "Global\" namespace. Some processes succeed, and some not; with the same permissions. Permissions set using ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor.

Inspecting the processes that do not behave as expected, I've added more permissions:

- User: Font Driver Host\UMFD-0
- SID: S-1-5-96-0-0

For this I've set: (A;OICI;GA;;;LS) // Since there is no such user on Microsoft's website

- User: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
- SID: S-1-5-20

For this I've set: A;OICI;GA;;;NS)

- User: NT AUTHORITY\LOCAL SERVICE
- SID: S-1-5-19

For this I've set: (A;OICI;GA;;;LS)

Some processes running under these permissions are able to read my object, and some not. Why is that ?

I will not use "Everyone" or empty/null DACL so please do not advise that as a solution. The idea is to "allow" what is necessary since windows denies everything by default.

Please point out what I am doing wrong, would really appreciate it.

Comment: Why is this getting down voted and to be closed ??

Comment: You'll find an answer to that question when reading [ask].

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you're setting the User-mode driver. Try to use `UD` instead of `LS`, This declaration is in the [`sddl.h`](https://github.com/tpn/winsdk-10/blob/master/Include/10.0.14393.0/shared/sddl.h#L218) file.

According to the rule of [AccessCheck](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/how-dacls-control-access-to-an-object#dacls),

> All ACEs have been checked and there is still at least one requested
>   access right that has not been explicitly allowed, in which case,
>   access is implicitly denied.

EDIT:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <sddl.h>
BOOL CreateMyDACL(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES* pSA)
{
    const TCHAR* szSD = TEXT("D:")
        TEXT("(A;OICI;GA;;;UD)")
        TEXT("(A;OICI;GA;;;NS)")
        TEXT("(A;OICI;GA;;;LS)"); 

    if (NULL == pSA)
        return FALSE;

    return ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor(
        szSD,
        SDDL_REVISION_1,
        &(pSA->lpSecurityDescriptor),
        NULL);
}
int main()
{
    TCHAR szName[] = TEXT("Global\\MyObject");
    SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES  sa;

    sa.nLength = sizeof(SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES);
    sa.bInheritHandle = FALSE;

    if (!CreateMyDACL(&sa))
    {
        printf("Failed CreateMyDACL\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    HANDLE hEvent = CreateEvent(&sa, FALSE, TRUE, szName);
    if (hEvent == NULL)
    {
        printf("error, %d\n", GetLastError());
        return -1;
    }
    else
        printf("success, %x\n", hEvent);
    //Sleep(10000); //

    CloseHandle(hEvent);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! This is for filterhost, and the rest ?

Comment: Not sure what you want to ask, but all SDDL user aliases are listed in `sddl.h`, you can refer to the comments after each `#define` from line 167 to 227.

Comment: Well for the "Font driver host" I understand I must use "UM", have not tested yet but I guess it will work. But for those processes that run under "NS" and "LS", why do I get Access Denied ? It makes no sense unless I am missing something. Only some of them cause this, like svchost (only some). Is there any other rights not listed or ?

Comment: I tested and "UD" gives invalid sid. Also this is not present on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/sid-strings.

Comment: Could you provide the sample you use to set the permissions, since In fact, `ConvertStringSecurityDescriptorToSecurityDescriptor` has no setting effect. Have you tried this sample: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/modifying-the-acls-of-an-object-in-c--

Comment: Of course this doesn't do anything on it's own, I use it for CreateEvent and similar objects in kernel space (Global\\, Local\\)..

Comment: If you check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createeventa it says clearly: "If an event is created from a service or a thread that is impersonating a different user, you can either apply a security descriptor to the event when you create it, or change the default security descriptor for the creating process by changing its default DACL." Well I am already doing that, I have tried setting the DACL as above, and tried without as well. Some "system" processes return access denied like if could not create the object... why ?

Comment: Do you get denied when creating, not when accessing?(such as failed from `CreateEvent`), I try your method but cannot repro it, even create the same object at the same time. The key point is how these "system" processes returned access denied are implemented. I have upload my sample that I tested.

Comment: Well I'm not sure how I can explain you to reproduce it, but I can tell you what I am doing. Creating event from within a system process like svchost, returns success and there is no issues. (Except when some instances do not allow local or global namespace, but that's a different story). If you try to then create it again from within that process, in this example svchost, even though the object is there it returns access denied. I'm not sure why, but it should return 183 which is already exists. Why it does return access denied.. is a mistery to me.

Comment: To reproduce what I said you need to be inside a system process, like svchost or fontdriverhost etc. I'm sure you know how to do this...

Comment: As a test result, if there is already an object with the same name, and it disables access of a user (such as "network service"), then "network service" will fail with access denied if it recreate.

Comment: But... why ? It makes no sense. if the process is running under user X and created the event, the next time it tries to create it again ( to check if it's there or not ) it should not give access denied since it's the same user X. It really makes no sense... and if you are right, how to solve it?

Comment: It seems I found the culprit! I was using CreateEventEx... and now tested without the "Ex" and it returns 183 - already exists as it should.